# How to use JSON.stringify replace to await Promise values?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, es6-promise, stringify

I have a JSON object I want to stringify. Some of the values in this object are Promises.

How can I use the `replacer` parameter in [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to pass the result of the Promise, instead of the promise itself?

To give a clear example of what I mean, let's assume the following object:

```js
const data = {
    foo: "foo",
    get bar() {
        return Promise.resolve('bar')
    },
    get baz() {
        return 'baz'
    },
}
```

If I call `JSON.stringify(data)`, the result is:

```json
{"foo":"foo","bar":{},"baz":"baz"}
```

But I want "bar" to be `bar` (similar to the result of "baz").

A naive attempt, using a replacer with async / await, doesn't work:

```js
const data = {
  foo: "foo",
  get bar() {
    return Promise.resolve('bar')
  },
  get baz() {
    return 'baz'
  },
}

const text = JSON.stringify(data, async(key, value) => {
  return value instanceof Promise ? await value : value
})

console.log(text)
```

So how *do* I get the value of the promise to be returned by the result of stringify?

Comment: You'll probably need to call all the promise methods, wait for their responses, and then stringify the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to deal with the promises first since the JSON.stringify method is synchronous.

```js
async function awaitAllObjectPromises(obj) {
  const newObj = { ...obj
  };
  const proms = [];
  for (const k in newObj) {
    if (newObj[k] instanceof Promise) {
      proms.push(newObj[k].then(v => newObj[k] = v));
    } else if (typeof newObj[k] === 'object' && newObj[k] !== null) {
      proms.push(awaitAllObjectPromises(newObj[k]).then(v => newObj[k] = v));
    }
  }
  await Promise.all(proms);
  return newObj;
}
async function test() {
  const data = {
    foo: "foo",
    get bar() {
      return Promise.resolve('bar')
    },
    get baz() {
      return 'baz'
    },
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(await awaitAllObjectPromises(data)));
}
test();
```

The idea is to go through all the object properties and find promises. Add them to a list of promises to have them resolve in parallel instead of sequentially (small optimization for objects with lots of promises). We do this recursively to make sure we catch all promises.

Using then() we make sure the promises get replaced with their resolved value, and we await them all.

Comment: I was afraid something like that was needed. So basically, it's a question of recursively resolving all Promises and then feeding the result to stringify? That's not too bad, I guess.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straightforward... The code I provided is not the easiest to read tough because it tries to optimize the promise resolutions. The use of awaits directly inside the loop would make things way clearer, but look out if there are a lot of promises inside the object.

Comment: Oh and I just realised it may not cover for arrays...

Comment: Yeah, I just ran into that in my implementation, but that's not too hard to resolve... Althought we might want to update the example code for future visitors who copy/paste the solution. Nice work by the way!

Comment: My implementation (without the Promise.all() optimisation) is this: https://gist.pother.ca/1601fc9985f81d91e7c232b14b998e05

Answer (score 1):

This solution makes a recursive resolve of your Promises in object & then u may to stringify it

```
async function resolvePromiseJSON(json){
        const copy = Object.assign({}, json)
        for(const key of Object.keys(copy)){
            let value = copy[key]

        const isPromise = value instanceof Promise 
        if(isPromise) value = await value
        
        const isArray = value instanceof Array
        if(isArray) value = Object.values(resolvePromiseJSON(value))

        const isObject = value instanceof Object
        if(isObject && !isArray) value = resolvePromiseJSON(value)
       
        copy[key] = value
    }
    return copy
}

resolvePromiseJSON(data).then(JSON.stringify)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).